# Any specific meaning behind the dictionary used in the this module

Tags: python

We can read the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) by `import this`, so I look into the package and found that the actual text is not written as it is but as:

```
Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
```

then use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)
```

to covert the characters, is there any specific reason behind that or it's just for fun?

Comment: Q predicted this

Comment: it's a Caesar cipher. It's just for fun. The entire module is just for fun.

Comment: It's actually a very specific Ceasar Cypher: ROT13. A simple swap of the two halves, and the only self-reversible variant of Ceasar's: running it twice will result in the original string again. Other numbers of Ceasar's don't do that.